# find in txt the value just before other value

Tags: python

This is little hard to explain.
I have for example two person_id and var inside each one, i need to get the person_id of the one that has a specific value.

```
 import json
 from pprint import pprint

 with open('aaaa.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
     data = json.loads(data_file.read())
```

like this:

```
"fileid": "7788994455",
     "nameid": "12345",
      "nameid": "54321",
      "nameid": "41124",
      "nameid": "000554",
                        "id": "9999999999",
                        "type": "single",
                        "data": {
                                "name": "John Smith",
                                "nameid": "12345",
                                "Gender": "Male",
                                }
                        "id": "88888888888",
                        "type": "single",
                        "data": {
                                "name": "Mary Smith",
                                "nameid": "54321",
                                "Gender": "Female",
                                }
                       "id": "777777777",
                        "type": "single",
                        "data": {
                                "name": "Mark Smith",
                                "nameid": "41124",
                                "Gender": "Male",
                                }
                        "id": "6666666666",
                        "type": "single",
                        "data": {
                                "name": "Jenny Smith",
                                "nameid": "000554",
                                "Gender": "Female",
                                }
```

I need to get to write to a txt like this,

ex:

```
fileid: 7788994455,nameid: 12345; nameid: Male

fileid: 7788994455,nameid: 54321; Gender: Female

fileid: 7788994455,nameid: 41124; nameid: Male

fileid: 7788994455,nameid: 000554; Gender: Female
```

can someone help?

Comment: do you need to search by `nameid`, `fileid` or some other field? Please specify in your question - this way people will be better able to help.

Comment: i need to write in a new txt the info like in the example

Comment: This looks like a JSON file. Have a look at the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) python module.

Comment: yes it is, thats the problem, i never work with json files :s

Comment: i got to open the file but how can i get this specific data

Comment: the JSON module parses your JSON and creates python dict from it. So If you know hot to getdata from dict there shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score -2):

```
print(data['fileid']['data']['nameid'])
```

Comment: Poor answer as there is no explanation.